# The underlying provider failed on Open Entity Framework when WCF Service to TCP/IP

Tags: wcf, entity-framework-4.1, tcp

I have an MVC application that access a WCF Service connected to Entity Framework.

I switched the connection from MVC application to WCF Service to TCP/IP from basichttp and now I get an error - the underlying provider failed on open. while accessing Entity Framework. this error doesnt happen on basichttp.

WCF service runs on IIS7.5 app pool is set to integrated mode.

connections string:

```
<add name="lc"  
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Lib.csdl|res://*/Lib.ssdl|res://*/Lib.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=OB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Not sure if this is related but I do not want to use sql server authentication only windows authentication.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

migrating to IIS caused a double hop issue. username and password was required in EntityFramework connection string. alternatively i granted the account application pool(in my case NTAUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) was running under permission in sql server database as I did not need impersonation.

Regards,
GM